# Googlemaps search with mongodb geospatial best strategy

Tags: google-maps, mongodb, geolocation

I have a website where people can view some places on a google map, which are stored with a lat/lng coordinate. The storage is mongodb. Now when the user navigates the map, I need to lookup up which places now are in the visible part of the map.

I'm new to mongo, but have looked at the spatial part. My question is now an effective way to do this lookup.

Do I need to make a ensureIndex each time the user navigates the map, and how do I then query all places within the visible boundaries of the map?

Comment: Make sure it also works around the map boundary... I know there aren't many places beyond Alaska at +-180°, but still someone might need it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to the mongo docs, you can query within a bounding box like so

```
box = [[40.73083, -73.99756], [40.741404,  -73.988135]]
db.places.find({"loc" : {"$within" : {"$box" : box}}})
```

The key point here is the use of **within** to query within a bounding box.

In order to get the values for your box, just get the bounds of the google map like so

```
map.getBounds()
```

Where map is your google maps object. getBounds will return a [LatLngBounds](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/reference.html#LatLngBounds) object from which you can build your box to query mongo.

As for ensureIndex, you should do that once as far as I know.

Comment: Should I then just do a db.places.ensureIndex( { loc : "2d" } ) and not specify anything about min/max?

Comment: Assuming you are mapping lat/lng values on earth with min/max -180/180 this loc:"2d" is sufficient without min/max, if you are mapping some other range of values, then you can control it with min/max values, but loc:"2d" with no min/max specified defaults to -180/180

Comment: you will get more detail in this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54919308/to-find-square-area-data-from-mongodb-query-using-2-google-map-point-latitude-a