# To find square area data from mongodb Query using 2 google map point (latitude and longitude)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query, geometry, geospatial

I am working on mongodb Geospatial feature.

Following is my db schema

```
{
    _id:5c6fea5aa7f54038cc63db92,
    location:{
        coordinates:[-96.81916,33.07516],
        type:"Point"
    },
    userId:1
}
```

> Indexing on **location** field with **2dsphere**

I have 2 point and each one have latitude and longitude  and its example is below

> **sw_latitude**: 32.76286484066411 **sw_longitude**: -96.91870791625979
>
> **ne_latitude**: 32.789133220783015  **ne_longitude**: -96.67529208374026

base on these 2 points i need to get all userId which are cover in these 2 points square

Can you please suggest me mongo query which give me result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried many way and finally i got one solution

**Step for solution 1:**

Step 1: find boundary from that 2 point

> **latitude:[32.740776 TO 32.8112099] AND longitude:[-96.910983 TO -96.683016]**

Step 2: use $box from Geospatial (ref: [$box from mongo](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/box/)) and pass this boundary point in that..

```
{    location: { 
       $geoWithin: { 
           $box:  [ [ 32.740776, 32.8112099 ], [ -96.910983, -96.683016 ] ] 
        }     
      } 
}
```

**Step for solution 2:**

Step 1: setup existing point proper way as following

> **latitude:[32.76286484066411 TO 32.789133220783015] AND longitude:[-96.91870791625979 TO -96.67529208374026]**

Step 2: use $box from Geospatial (ref: [$box from mongo](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/box/)) and pass this boundary point in that..

```
{    location: { 
       $geoWithin: { 
           $box:  [ [ 32.76286484066411,  32.789133220783015 ], [ -96.91870791625979, -96.67529208374026 ] ] 
        }     
      } 
}
```

Hope will be helpful for you